# How to start a dummy process in bash which will start another seven descendant processes

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a bash script which would log all descendants process information in below format but I have to log the info only when a process has more than six descendants process.

| PID | PPID | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 9 | 1 (indicates child) |
| 9 | 8 | 2 (indicates parent) |
| 8 | 7 | 3 (indicates grand parent) |

```
Pstree -ps 10 should display:
dummy1---dummy2---dummy3---dummy4---dummy5---dummy6---dummy7
```

How to trigger dummy process in above manner?

Frankly I have no idea about bash script, only thing i was able to do was display PID's of a particular user.

```
while read -r processId;
do
    echo $processId
done <<< "$(ps -u $USER -o pid)"
```

I need to loop each PID & check if it has more than six descendants but before that I want to manually trigger six descendants process to start & test my script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start a script with seven descendants, you can use something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]; then
    set -- 7
fi

if [[ "$1" -gt 2 ]]; then
    "$0" "$(($1 - 1))"
else
    sleep 120
fi
```

or more compactly,

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ "$#" -ne 1 ]] && set -- 7

[[ $1 -gt 2 ]] && $0 $(($1 - 1)) || sleep 120
```

If this is given no or too many arguments, it sets its argument to 7. Then as long as its argument is greater than 2, it starts a child running the same script, with a decremented argument. When the argument reaches 2, it runs a two-minute sleep. (The limit is two because the last script and the `sleep` also count as one each.)

```
$ ./dummy &
$ pstree -p 1800554
dummy(1800554)───dummy(1800561)───dummy(1800563)───dummy(1800566)───dummy(1800567)───dummy(1800570)───sleep(1800572)
```

You can request a different number of children by changing the argument:

```
$ ./dummy 6 &
```

This can be extended to start multiple children in each “generation”:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

[[ "$#" -ne 2 ]] && set -- 1 7

for (( i = 0; i < $1; i++ )); do
[[ $2 -gt 2 ]] && $0 $1 $(($2 - 1)) || sleep 120 &
done
wait
```

Run it as

```
./dummy 3 2 &
```

to start two generations with three children each.